# I want to export my phpmyadmin data from database to printable card

Tags: phpmyadmin

.just I have one database and there are many fields in that database . so what I  want to do is , which fields I imported in the database that fields I want to print on one card that is I want to export that all field with the card in pdf format. so I can print each field data on a new card. t[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LtH6t.png).also I attached here the format of card that I want to print .

Answer (score 0):

You can export the file in the open document spreadsheet. Open it. Use windows Snipping tool to snip out the contents you need and then export your file to pdf. That will make it look like you showed in the image

Comment: no thats not the problem i want the fields in the database that to be directly printed on the card template.